# Lyapunov function for an arbitrary equilibrium point

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Typically, Lyapunov function assumes $0$ as an equilibrium and require $V(0)=0$. If we wanted to analyze the stability of a nonzero equilibrium point $x_0$, most references asks to do a state transformation $x’=x-x_0$.

Instead, can we / why can’t we require that $V(x_0)=0$ and positive everywhere else?

Comment: Of course we can.

Comment: More generally, the theorem tells you the Lyapunov function must have a single minimum (i.e. if not globally then locally).

Answer (score 0):

If it is a nonzero equilibrium point $x_{0}$, you can shift it to a new coordinate. Take this system for example:
$$
\dot{x} = - x + x_{0}
$$
and introduce the error
$$
e = x - x_{0}.
$$
Taking the time derivative of $e$ and make the necessary substitutions
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \dot{e} &= \dot{x} - \dot{x}_{0} \\
 \dot{e} &= - x + x_{0} - \dot{x}_{0} \\
 \dot{e} &= - x + x_{0} \\
 \dot{e} &= - \left(x - x_{0}\right) \\
 \dot{e} &= - e. \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Consider the Lyapunov function candidate, which has the quadratic form such that $V\left(0\right) = 0$ and $V\left(e\right) > 0$ for all $e$ with $e \neq 0$:
$$
V\left(e\right) = \frac{1}{2} e^{2}.
$$
Now, take the time derivative along the trajectory of the error system
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \dot{V}\left(e\right) &= \frac{dV}{de} \frac{de}{dt} \\
 \dot{V}\left(e\right) &= e \dot{e} \\
 \dot{V}\left(e\right) &= - e^{2} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
The result implies that $\dot{V} < 0$ for all $e$ with $e \neq 0$, and it means $e = 0$ is asymptotically stable. So by logic, when $e \rightarrow 0$, then $x \rightarrow x_{0}$.